# Jenkins agent(jnlp) Got permission denied /var/run/docker.sock on kubernetes

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I deployed Jenkins via Helm chart([jenkins-helm:3.11.4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/releases/tag/jenkins-3.11.4)) on my local Kubernetes cluster(rancher desktop). I installed docker on `jenkins/inbound-agent` image because it is not included where I am using the default Jenkins-controller image as provided. When I run the docker command in the local pipeline I am getting a permission error as below.

I am aware that, the issue is the permission for /var/run/.docker.sock folder but I could not fix it and really stuck. I tried to add `command:["sh","-c","chmod 777 /var/run/.docker.sock ]` to the agent in values.yaml but this time jenkins did not up and running properly. I tried to add `RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins` to the Dockerfile but still same.

```
jenkins@default-cnmq7:~/agent$ id
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins),0(root)
jenkins@default-cnmq7:~/agent$ grep docker /etc/group
docker:x:107:
```

So how can I grant permission for this folder through the helm chart for Jenkins agent pod? Or what is the proper solution to fix this issue.

```
node {
  stage('SCM') {
    checkout(scm)
  }
  stage('Build') {
    echo 'Building Project'
    sh """
      docker pull alpine
    """
  }
}

 [Pipeline] sh
    + docker pull alpine
    Using default tag: latest
    Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=alpine&tag=latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

values.yaml

```
    controller:
      componentName: "jenkins-controller"
      image: "jenkins"
      # tag: "2.319.3-jdk11"
      tagLabel: jdk11
      imagePullPolicy: "Always"
      imagePullSecretName:
      javaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m" 
      jenkinsUrl: "http://localhost:8080"
    agent:
      enabled: true
      defaultsProviderTemplate: ""
      # URL for connecting to the Jenkins contoller
      jenkinsUrl:
      jenkinsTunnel:
      image: "jenkins/inbound-agent"
      tag: "4.11.2-5"
      workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      nodeUsageMode: "NORMAL"
      componentName: "jenkins-agent"
      websocket: false
      privileged: true
      runAsUser: 
      runAsGroup:
      alwaysPullImage: true
      podRetention: "Never"
      volumes:
      - type: HostPath
        hostPath: /Users/username/workspace
        mountPath: /Users/username/workspace
      - type: HostPath
        hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
        mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      command:
      args: "${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}"
```

Dockerfile for jenkins agent

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:4.11.2-4
USER root
RUN set -eux && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl sudo docker.io docker-compose && \
    curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HariSekhon/bash-tools/master/clean_caches.sh | sh
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

Comment: is `docker-deamon` running inside agent?

Answer (score 1):

First find the group id of docker from the Host

```
$ grep docker /etc/group
docker:x:999:
```

Then create a user in the Dockerfile which its group is the same is docker group id.

```
RUN groupadd -g 999 tech
RUN useradd -g tech tech
USER tech
```

Comment: it is `docker:x:107:jenkins`.. So do I have to change the command `RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins` with the ones that you mentioned? Like below
`RUN groupadd -g 107 tech RUN useradd -g jenkins jenkins USER jenkins`

Comment: instead of creating a user, cant I use the jenkins user?

Comment: Yes, you can just create the group with the same gid and then add your user to that group

Comment: I am still getting a permission error. I just add the output of id information.. Can you please update your answer according to the information that I added.

Comment: do This:
RUN groupadd -g 107 tech
RUN usermod -aG tech jenkins
-

Comment: Doesn't this mean the image won't be usable on other hosts with a different group IDfor docker?